# For show particular Records using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javaScript with jQuery. I am having some data, but it display two time.

```
<input type="hidden" id="btnlistTime" /> 
for(var i = 0; i < msg.driverList.length; i++){
      $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             url: "data/get_lastReportedTime.php",
             data: {Driver: msg.driverList[i].fullname}
      }).done(function (data){
          $('#btnlistTime').val(data);
          for(var i = 0; i < msg.driverList.length; i++){ 
              OnlineDriver.push([msg.driverList[i].id,
                                 msg.driverList[i].fullname,
                                 $('#btnlistTime').val(),
                                 msg.driverList[i].lat,
                                 msg.driverList[i].lng,
                                 msg.driverList[i].logintime]);
          }
      });
 }
 UpdateOnlineDriver(OnlineDriver);

 function UpdateOnlineDriver(data) {

     tableOnlineDriver = $('#tblDriverDetails').dataTable({
         "data": data,
         "bFilter": true,
         "stateSave": true,
         "columnDefs": [            
                {"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [3]},
                {"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [4]},
                {"sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [5]}
         ]
  });
}
```

And Using ajax i get last time from DataBase and add into msg.driverList, it was came from socket,Like this.

```
('1059', 'Ashish', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1060', 'Ashish1', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1061', 'Bhargav', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '0987654321');
```

But issue is when i referece the page it was showed like this,

```
('1059', 'Ashish', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1059', 'Ashish', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1060', 'Ashish1', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1060', 'Ashish1', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1061', 'Bhargav', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '0987654321');
('1061', 'Bhargav', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '0987654321');
```

so please help me how can i solve it,i want to show like,

```
('1059', 'Ashish', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1060', 'Ashish1', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '1324567890');
('1061', 'Bhargav', '9.962479', '-84.082434', '0987654321');
```

please help me, thax for advance.

Comment: What do want to display in `btnlistTime`: you are overwriting it in each iteration, so only the last value you set to it will remain...

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the variable name in for-loop as below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < msg.driverList.length; i++){
  $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "data/get_lastReportedTime.php",
         data: {Driver: msg.driverList[i].fullname}
  }).done(function (data){
      $('#btnlistTime').val(data);
      // change var "i" to "j"
      for(var j = 0; j < msg.driverList.length; j++){ 
          OnlineDriver.push([msg.driverList[j].id,
                             msg.driverList[j].fullname,
                             $('#btnlistTime').val(),
                             msg.driverList[j].lat,
                             msg.driverList[j].lng,
                             msg.driverList[j].logintime]);
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

- The asynchronously executed code within the function you provide to `done` will execute *after* your call `UpdateOnlineDriver(OnlineDriver)`. So first the whole outer `for` loop will be executed, then `UpdateOnlineDriver` and only then the callback function given to `done` will start getting called. To solve this, you need to call it from within the `done` callback, and only when you have retrieved the last data.
- It makes no sense to have a `for` loop within the callback function, as it will be called separately for each driver already (cf. outer loop): just count the number of `push` calls you will be doing: for each iteration of the outer loop, you will iterate again all drivers and perform the `push`. So that is a quadratic amount of pushes. Cannot be what you want.
- Once the inner `for` loop is removed, you'll have the issue of how the variable *i* first runs to the end, and only then the callback function is called that many of times, each with the value of *i* equal at the length of the array. But you'll want to get different values of *i* in each call of the callback. For that to happen, there are many solutions, one of which is to use `let` instead of `var`.

Here is the proposed correction of the `for` loop part:

```
// Use "let" instead of "var" to have a locally scoped variable
// which is available within the $.ajax callback
for(let i = 0; i < msg.driverList.length; i++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "data/get_lastReportedTime.php",
        data: {Driver: msg.driverList[i].fullname}
    }).done(function (data){
        // Do not iterate here.
        $('#btnlistTime').val(data);
        OnlineDriver.push([
            msg.driverList[i].id,
            msg.driverList[i].fullname,
            $('#btnlistTime').val(),
            msg.driverList[i].lat,
            msg.driverList[i].lng,
            msg.driverList[i].logintime
        ]);
        // If this is the last entry, then call out
        if (i === msg.driverList.length-1) {
            UpdateOnlineDriver(OnlineDriver)
        }
    });
}
```

Note that you will overwrite the value of `btnlistTime` again and again, so it will finally just display the data retrieved for the last driver.